# Вызов активити из уведомления без многократного создавания новых Activity

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, activity, android-notification

По нажатию кнопки создаю сервис, в котором в функции onStartCommand создаю уведомление

```
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("My notification")
                    .setContentText("Hello World!");
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, myIntent,
            0);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
}
```

Выхожу из приложения. По нажатию на уведомление запускается активити, всё ОК. Проблема в том, что если я не выхожу из приложения кнопкой Back, а нажимаю кнопку Home, то при нажатии на уведомление у меня создается новое активити. И если я сделаю так 10 раз, то потом нужно 10 раз нажать кнопку Back, чтобы выйти из приложения. Как решить проблему?

Comment: Вот тут описано решение http://stackoverflow.com/a/12043699/4829111

Comment: вопрос на англ. SO с правильным ответом на ваш: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163367/resume-an-activity-when-clicked-on-a-notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`4` аргументом метода `getActivity` класса `PendingIntent` передаются флаги, сообщающие методу подробности о параметрах запуска активити. В вашем случае туда надо передать флаг `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, коий как раз позволяет открыть ранее запущенную, не уничтоженную системой активити вместо создания (по умолчанию, без флагов) нового её экземпляра.

`PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, resultIntentToActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`

И добавить аттрибут к активити в манифесте:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Comment: Попробовал - не помогло. Не плохо бы выяснить почему. P.S. Если прописать android:launchMode="singleTask" в манифесте, то работает как надо.

Comment: @Art7, дополнил сим ответ.

Comment: А почему работает если просто добавить аттрибут в манифест?

Comment: @Art7, ну, видимо с этим андроид всегда создаёт только один экземпляр активити_