# Проблема с PendingIntent в BroadcastReceiver'е

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notification, android-broadcastreceiver, pendingintent

**AlarmReceiver:**

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.i(this::class.simpleName, "onReceive")
        context?.let {
            val taskId = intent?.getIntExtra(TASK_ID, -1)
            showNotification(it, taskId)
        }
    }

    private fun showNotification(context: Context, taskId: Int?) {
        Log.i(this::class.simpleName, "showNotification")
        if (taskId != -1) {
            taskId?.let {
                val intent = TaskActivity.newIntentById(context, taskId.toString())
                val pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, it, intent, 0)

                val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "")
                    .setContentTitle("Test Title")
                    .setContentText("Test text")
                    .setContentIntent(pi)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_android_24)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .build()

                val manager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
                manager.notify(it, notification)
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TASK_ID = "com.voak.android.tasklist.services.alarmreceiver.task_id"

        fun newIntent(context: Context, taskId: Int): Intent {
            val intent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(TASK_ID, taskId)
            return intent
        }
    }
}
```

**TaskActivity:**

```
class TaskActivity : BaseActivity() {

    override fun getLayoutRes(): Int {
        return R.layout.activity_task
    }

    companion object {
        private const val EXTRA_TYPE = "com.voak.android.tasklist.views.activities.taskactivity.task_type"
        private const val EXTRA_TASK_ID = "com.voak.android.tasklist.views.activities.taskactivity.task_id"

        fun newIntent(context: Context, type: Int): Intent {
            val intent = Intent(context, TaskActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TYPE, type)

            return intent
        }

        fun newIntentById(context: Context, taskId: String): Intent {
            val intent = Intent(context, TaskActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TASK_ID, taskId)

            Log.i(this::class.simpleName, "newIntentById $taskId")

            return intent
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(getLayoutRes())

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            val type = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_TYPE, -1)
            val id = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_TASK_ID)

            if (type != -1) {
                viewRouter.navigateToTaskFragment(type)
            } else if (!id.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                viewRouter.navigateToTaskFragment(id)
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что в `AlarmReceiver`е в строке `val intent = TaskActivity.newIntentById(context, taskId.toString())` `taskId` передается верно, но в самом активити `val id = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_TASK_ID)` возвращает `null`, из-за чего не могу открыть нужный фрагмент. Не могу понять, что не так, помогите.

Comment: Попробуйте поиграться с `launchMode` активити в манифесте, флагами для PendingIntent и переопределить `onNewIntent` в активити.

Comment: Вроде бы вот тут немного подробностей: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/490260/17609

Comment: попробуйте добавить флаг в PendingIntent FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT, если поможет я оформлю ответ

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, действительно флаг для PendingIntent FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT помог.